# How do I pass DateTime as a parameter in PowerShell?

Tags: datetime, powershell, parameters

I have a script that's calling another script and passing in parameters along with it. Whenever I try to pass in a datetime, parts of the datetime are used as arguments for the other parameters.

#### script1.ps1

```
$dateEnd = Get-Date "12/31/14"
$siteUrl = "http://foo.com"
$outputPath = "c:\myFolder"

$argumentList = "-file .\script2.ps1", "test1", $dateEnd, $siteUrl, $outputPath
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList $argumentList
```

#### script2.ps1

```
param
(
     [string]$test1,
     [DateTime]$dateEnd,
     [string]$siteUrl,
     [string]$outputFile
)      

$test1
$dateEnd
$siteUrl
$outputFile

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

This would result in:

```
test1
Wednesday, December 31, 2014 12:00:00 AM
00:00:00
http://foo.com
```

EDIT - string as date, typo on my part:

If I pass the string `12/31/14` it works fine, but I'd like to be able to pass a date.

Comment: First, please show us desired output. Second, that would not result in what you specified. You don't reference anything that would output `00:00:00` anywhere in Script2.ps1, also, you do echo `$outputFile` but don't show `c:\myFolder` in your results.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Hi!  His first line creates a datetime object.  The datetime is parsed into a string and thus taken in as two positional arguments.  This is where the 00:00:00 comes from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the line which assigns $argumentList, change the $dateEnd parameter to be `$dateEnd.toString('s')`.

Arguments to Windows processes are strings, and not objects, so [Start-Process](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) must convert the ArgumentList into a string. Powershell.exe then parses that string by splitting on spaces (like any Windows process), and it turns it back into your parameters.

Normally, this should work perfectly well, but in this case notice what happens when you run `(get-date).tostring()`. The default output for a DateTime object contains a space, which is interfering with the parsing.

The solution, then, is to format the date parameter in your argument list to have no spaces and yet still be in a format that DateTime::Parse() can understand (so PowerShell can reload the variable on the other end).  Passing `'s'` to DateTime::toString() gives you such a format.

Comment: Ha, this is it. Thank you. Didn't realize passing a string was required.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to a combination of positional parameter usage and quoting.  Here's a single change that should make it work (quoted the date input):

```
$argumentList = "-file D:\script2.ps1", "test1", "`"$dateEnd`"", $siteUrl, $outputPath
```

Is there any reason you call a separate PowerShell process?  You could call this like so:

```
#This will run in separate scope 
    & ".\script2.ps1" test1 $dateEnd $siteUrl $outputPath

#This will run in the local (current) scope:
    . ".\script2.ps1" test1 $dateEnd $siteUrl $outputPath
```

Comment: The reason I'm calling it as a separate process is because I need to return some audit logs which get really big and I want to be able to free memory each time since disposing the object after use was not freeing memory as I intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue of you not using DateTime objects correctly. If you want to specify a date, then do so. What you suggest as your string is a Time, not a date. If you want to specify **both** then provide both to Get-Date.

```
$endDate = "12/31/14 08:00:00"
```

That's 8:00 AM on December 31st.

Then in your script call whatever it is that you want specifically.

```
param
(
     [string]$test1,
     [DateTime]$dateEnd,
     [string]$siteUrl,
     [string]$outputFile
)      

$test1
$dateEnd.ToLongDateString()
$dateEnd.ToLongTimeString()
$siteUrl
$outputFile
```

When a DateTime object is passed to that (shown here with your other test data) you should get:

```
test1
Wednesday, December 31, 2014
8:00:00 AM
http://foo.com
C:\myfolder
```